# Why ulimit -n modifies hard limit

Tags: ulimit

Checking open files (soft) limit on current shell

```
/home/pkaramol
$  ulimit -n
1024
```

Checking hard limit

```
/home/pkaramol
$ ulimit -n -H
1048576
```

Setting (soft) limit to hard limit value and verifying it worked:

```
/home/pkaramol
$ ulimit -n hard
/home/pkaramol
$ ulimit -n
1048576
```

The question is why the following command modifies the **BOTH** **hard** and **soft** limits, given that when no switch is provided, the default is that operations take place on soft limit

```
/home/pkaramol
$ ulimit -n 2048
/home/pkaramol
$ ulimit -n 
2048
/home/pkaramol
$ ulimit -n -H
2048
```

At what point was the hard limit lowered to `2048` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is `ulimit` built into the `bash` shell, then specifying neither of `-H` or `-S` when *setting* a limit will set both the hard and the soft resource limits.

This is documented in the `bash` manual:

> `ulimit [-HSabcdefiklmnpqrstuvxPT [limit]]`
>
> Provides control over the resources available to the shell and to  processes  started  by
>           it,  on  systems that allow such control.  The `-H` and `-S` options specify that the hard or
>           soft limit is set for the given resource.  A hard limit cannot be increased by a non-root
>           user once it is set; a soft limit may be increased up to the value of the hard limit.  **If
>           neither `-H` nor `-S` is specified, both the soft and hard limits  are  set.**

The `ksh93` shell has a similar wording in its manual,

> If neither the `H` nor `S` option is specified, the limit applies to both.

... and the `zsh` and `dash` shells also behaves the same with regards to setting the limits.